# I am unable to rename application package name in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

At first I got an error while exporting my android app in eclipse:

> AndroidManifest.xml does not declare a Java package: Build aborted.

I posted this problem in various forums and one guy told me to do these steps:

1. you need to enter a valid Bundle ID for Google Play. Something similar to "com.company.gamename".
2. Don't use any special characters.

BUT whenever I try to click on rename application package, the menu disappears and nothing shows up.

Please Help...

Answer (score 1):

From the error **"AndroidManifest.xml does not declare a Java package: Build aborted."** it looks like your AndroidManifest.xml file has missing **"package:com.xxx.xxx"** attribute.

You need to confirm on this by double checking AndoridManifest.xml file.

You can try refreshing entire project from project->right-click-menu>refresh. This will fetch latest content from file.